# How to check whether checkbox is checked in WordPress customizer

Tags: plugin-development

I am building a plugin and I want to add some settings which rely on checkboxes. 
 I know how to get data from the checkbox in PHP but got stuck in WordPress. Because we have no option to add the name attribute to the checkbox. for example, I am adding a checkbox in the customizer.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('ion', array(
        'sanitize_callback' => 'ion_checkbox'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'ion', array(
        'label' => 'Check',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'section' => 'search_submit_section',
        'settings' => 'ion'
    )));
```

As we see there is no option to add name attribute. How we will know whether the user has checked the checkbox or not. I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

It has been quite some time, but you can simply check if the mod value is `true` or `false`.

```
    <?php
    if( get_theme_mod('ion') == true ){
       //your html
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sanitizing a checkbox is quite easy. Since the checkbox value is either true or false (1 or 0), you simply need to return one of these values. A simple function can be written that tests if the checkbox has been set, and if so, it returns 1 otherwise it returns 0.

```
 function mytheme_chkbox_sanitization( $input ) {
if ( true === $input ) {
    return 1;
 } else {
    return 0;
 }
}
```

When creating the Setting for your Checkbox, pass the name of this function 
   to the sanitize_callback argument.

```
 $wp_customize->add_setting( 'sample_default_checkbox',
 array(
    'default' => 0,
    'sanitize_callback' => 'mytheme_chkbox_sanitization',
 )
);
```

Comment: i checked this code before on github but this is not the answer. please provide other example of sanitize callback function because that function i am not getting.

Comment: I have edit it. Usually I use if statements that work fine. Are you sure you didn't miss something?

Comment: i am still not getting how will i use get_theme_mod because i am creating checkbox from here not anywhere in html. i think it will generate error

Comment: Check other example of sanitize

Comment: @dado My lap shutdown. Now messaging from phone using other account. Yes I agree checkbox has either true or false value. So if user checks checkbox then I want to use add_action, how to do that